# Arranging ascending descending order of RingCentral text

Tags: sms, ringcentral

We are using RingCentral desktop apps to text messages (send/receive). We are receiving lot of incoming text messages there.

In RingCentral desktop app how to setup and arrange text messages in ascending or descending order?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this kind of feature is still not there in RingCentral desktop application.

You can make a feature request [in the RingCentral Ideas portal here](https://ideas.ringcentral.com/ideas/search?page=4&query=Salesforce). They use this portal to track requested features from users to implement in future.
You can refer to a similar kind of question [here](https://community.ringcentral.com/questions/100971/how-do-i-set-rc-messages-to-ascending-orderhow-do.html).